# digital signature on any item using certificates stored in active directory

Tags: signature, digital

I want to know the ability to perform the signature on a data record ( Workflow item for example) using certificates Stored in Active directory.

I guess the signing operation will be : get the certificate of a user from active directory and generate a signature to sign the Data with it. ==> "how to get a certificate of a certain user?!"

and I guess the verifying operation will be : compare the public key stored in the signature , with all public keys of certificates in active directory , till finding the matching one , to guarantee it is a verified signature

Is that true please ? do i miss the implementation of CRL check ? and trusting certificate in windows Trust Store? where to save public Keys?